# Как сделать циклический ввод данных?

Tags: java, android

Возможно заголовок сформулирован неверно. В приложении генерируются случайные числа и операнд т.е математический пример, снизу EditText и кнопка. Проблема: при нажатии на кнопку ответ проверяется все ок, но после одного раза все останавливается, чтобы снова появилась задача надо выйти и зайти. Как сделать так чтобы вопросы генерировались производное количество раз, чтобы мог отвечать на них тоже?

код без подключения библиотек:

```
public class QuestionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    TextView textView;
    EditText answer;
    int a = (int) ( Math.random() * 11 );
    int b = (int) ( Math.random() * 11 );
    int c = a+b;

    String a1 = String.valueOf(a);
    String b1 = String.valueOf(b);

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(a1 + "+" + b1);
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        answer = findViewById(R.id.answer);
        answer.setClickable(!(answer.getText().toString().trim().equals("")));
        btn = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        double Answer = Double.parseDouble(answer.getText().toString());
                        textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);

                        if (c == Answer) {
                            textView.setText("Верно!");
                        } else {
                            textView.setText("Ошибка!");
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто по нажатию на кнопку генерировать новые данные, например, так:

```
public class QuestionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    TextView textView;
    EditText answer;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    String a1;
    String b1;

    void generateTask(){
        a = (int) ( Math.random() * 11 );
        b = (int) ( Math.random() * 11 );
        c = a+b;
        a1 = String.valueOf(a);
        b1 = String.valueOf(b);
        textView.setText(a1 + "+" + b1);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        generateTask();
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    bool flag = false;

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        answer = findViewById(R.id.answer);
        answer.setClickable(!(answer.getText().toString().trim().equals("")));
        btn = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    double Answer = Double.parseDouble(answer.getText().toString());

                    flag = !flag;
                    if(flag){
                        btn.setText("Продолжить");
                        if (c == Answer) {
                            textView.setText("Верно!");
                        } else {
                            textView.setText("Ошибка!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        btn.setText("Проверить"); //вероятно, у Вас другой текст
                        generateTask();
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.